# Quantiles in Prometheus Summary - What can I do with them in PromQL

Tags: prometheus

I have a summary metric for endpoint latency "my_metric_api_latency_seconds" with a few quantiles calculated by the client for e.g. p50, p90, p95, p99 etc and I also have a set of labels associated with the metric.

consider I have the following time-series as:
my_metric_api_latency_seconds{host="host-1.win", instance="local", api="/api/foo", status="200", quantile=".95"} = 0.05

my_metric_api_latency_seconds{host="host-2.win", instance="web", api="/api/foo", status="200", quantile=".95"} = 0.76

my_metric_api_latency_seconds{host="host-3.win", instance="native", api="/api/foo", status="200", quantile=".95"} = 0.55

We know that summary quantiles are not aggregatable. Since, the quantiles are calculated by the client, PromQL queries are much faster as well.

My question is

- How can I use PromQL query which will give me the overall p95 latency
  results for the endpoint "api/foo" over all the hosts.
- If I have another time series for another endpoint for e.g. my_metric_api_latency_seconds{host="host-1.win", instance="local", 
  api="/api/foo2", status="200", quantile=".95"} = 0.05. How can I use PromQL query to give me the overall latency of host = "host-1.win" aggregated over all the other labels.

Answer (score 2):

As you say, quantiles are not aggregatable so these queries are not possible with this input data. You could use the `_sum` and `_count` of the [Summary to calculate an average or use a Histogram instead if you want a quantile](https://www.robustperception.io/common-query-patterns-in-promql/).

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately [Prometheus-style summary quantiles](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#summary) cannot be aggregated :( So it is recommended switching to [Histograms](https://prometheus.io/docs/concepts/metric_types/#histogram) instead if aggregation over multiple metrics is needed. Prometheus provides [histogram_quantile](https://docs.victoriametrics.com/MetricsQL.html#histogram_quantile) function, which can be used for dynamic quantiles' calculation across histogram buckets. For example, the following query returns 95th [percentile](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percentile) over `my_metric_api_latency_seconds` histogram grouped by `host`:

```
histogram_quantile(0.95, sum(rate(my_metric_api_latency_seconds_bucket[5m])) by (host,le))
```

P.S. It may be hard to choose the correct set of buckets for Prometheus-style histograms. See [this article](https://valyala.medium.com/improving-histogram-usability-for-prometheus-and-grafana-bc7e5df0e350) for possible issues and solutions.